# Is there any method to check whether called number is switched OFF or ON...?

Tags: android

I am developing some application in which i need to know the called number's state  whether    swithed off or on and this is to be done in android any suggestions how can we do this..?

Comment: You want to know whether the remote phone you are calling is switched on or not?

Comment: YES i want to know the remote phone's state...

Comment: Not possible - all that you know is whether the call was answered or not

Comment: if call is not answered then can we know that..?

Answer (score 0):

Simply NO...
This is the matter of Network providers (GSM, CDMA etc.), and they cannot determine this as well...

Comment: if call is not answered then can we know that..?

Comment: No, if call is not answered lead to many reasons like user didn't respond it, user is out of network access area, user has problem in phone, he/she has low balance (some cases) or service provider some how blocked it...
So you cant determine why we can't make call to user.